# Tools to monitor Oracle Database Performance on Standard Edition

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-se

Here is what I am looking for:

- Works on Standard Edition i.e. No Diagnostic Pack.
- Provides both current and historical performance data.
- Good visuals for easy spotting of trends and presentation to management.

If you have used the tool, I would be interested in pros and cons you have discovered.  I can come up with a list, but the insight of actually having used the tool is worth far more.

Answer (score 5):

*Note: I've never used this, so please edit this answer if you have.*

[Lab128](http://www.lab128.com/lab128_features.html)

[image: Screen Capture of Application A]

[image: Screen Capture of Application B]

> Lab128 provides additional savings by implementing ASH functions and
>   not requiring the purchase of ODP.

Pros:

- Response Time Analysis
- RAC support
- Agentless
- Only $299 for a named user connecting to two instances and only $499 for a named user connecting to an unlimited number of instances.

Cons:

- Interface isn't very polished.
- Lack of alerts.
- One writer/maintainer.
- No web interface.
- Not server based.

Answer (score 5):

Foglight Perf.Analysis for Oracle is a great performance workload tool which digs very deep into Oracle via Stealthcollect technologie direct from server memory areas, so no much overhead load in the database, also possible to review historical data, change tracking, advisories and much more...

[image: Foglight screenshot from Webcast]
[image: Foglight screenshot from pdf]

StealthCollect – Delivers deep SQL-level collection and analysis at a fraction of the overhead of running a trace or executing direct SQL against production.

Performance Advisories – Reviews workload data and produces custom reports to maximize performance through built-in analytics and business intelligence.

IntelliProfile – Tracks database behavior and identifies abnormal activity with a sophisticated baselining algorithm.

Statement-Level Wait-Event Analysis – Reveals wait-event data down to the statement level, speeding resolution of resource-related performance problems.

QuickCompare – Provides a shortcut for identifying the root causes and symptoms of performance deviations in application environments.

Integrated Reporting – Provides targeted, built-in reports. With easy-to-use wizards, you can define, customize, generate, schedule, and deliver reports on system health, performance, trends, changes, and a variety of other topics and data points.

Long-Term Performance Repository – Delivers unlimited performance and environmental data storage and dimensional analysis in an Oracle database.

Automated Change Tracking – Identifies and sends notifications of changes to server, instance, database, schema environments, and application SQL degradations.

Please also take a look at Spotlight on Oracle (RAC) is real time diagnostics from an Oracle architecture level.

We use these tools with Oracle healthchecks and performance investigations.

Pros:

- Response time analysis
- Server Based
- RAC Aware

Cons:

- Cost

Comment: Hi Donald and welcome to dba.se - thanks for your contribution here and please may I ask that you [disclose your affiliation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers) with any company involved in producing or selling tools you endorse, if any affiliation does exist. If not please say here to that effect and I'll remove my comment!

Comment: Thanks Donald for the post (+1).  Since you have experience with the product could you list any cons?  Is it difficult to setup, does it cost a lot, are there annoying aspects to it, etc?

Answer (score 4):

[Ignite](http://www.confio.com/English/Products/Ignite_for_Oracle.php) by Confio Softwar.e  From their website:

> Ignite for Oracle is the one Oracle database performance monitoring
>   solution that identifies, analyzes and resolves all of the performance
>   problems affecting applications and users depending on an Oracle
>   database.
>
> Ignite doesn’t just show health metrics, it correlates the most
>   important performance data to build a complete picture of Oracle
>   database performance for the DBA, Developer and DBA manager. Response
>   time, queries, sessions and server resources, are all analyzed by
>   Ignite Performance Intelligence to show both historical and real-time
>   conditions affecting database applications.

[image]

Pros:

- Response Time Analysis
- Agentless
- Server Based
- Web interface
- Free Version for basic info
- Can be RAC and/or VMWare aware

Cons:

- Drilldowns not as in depth as OEM
- Users must be maintained independently
- Cost

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I've never used this, so please edit this answer if you have.*

[WISE (Workload Interface Statistical Engine)](http://www.wise-oracle.com/index.html) uses Statspack to show graphical performance trend information.

[image: WISE Screenshot 1]

[image: WISE Screenshot 2]

Pros:

- Response Time Analysis
- Enterprise Edition - $349/database or $3,900/unlimited.
- Server based.
- Alerts.

Cons:

- Interface isn't very polished.
- Web interface is extra cost and doesn't have all the features.
- Not RAC Aware

Answer (score 2):

[MindArray IPM](http://mindarraysystems.com) by MindArray Systems

Pros:

- Response time analysis
- Server Based
- RAC support
- Free Version for basic info
- Allows a specific time range selection
- Easy To Use

Cons:

- Not a Open Source

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this vendor/product?

Answer (score 2):

W-ASH is free, works on Standard Edition as well as Enterprise (i.e. it doesn't need Oracle's `v$active_session_history`) and runs in a web browser window.

http://www.oraclerealworld.com/web-ash-w-ash/

[image: monitor]

I'm the creator of W-ASH. I'm also the principal designer of Enterprise Managers performance screens. The "Top Activity" screen has been called the "Kyle Screen". I designed Embarcadero's DB Optimizer with similar interface and I've advised on Lab128 for free just because I think it's a super cool tool. I worked at Quest and tried to gear Spotlight more like Top Activity but Quest disagreed, so I went to Oracle and created Top Activity. I also have a free tool in TCL/TK called [ASHMON](http://kylehailey.com/ash-masters/ashmon/)

Answer (score 1):

[ASHViewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashv/) is a free alternative.  Description from the readme:

> ASH Viewer provides graphical Top Activity, similar Top Activity
>   analysis and Drilldown of Oracle Enterprise Manager performance page.
>   ASH Viewer store ASH data locally using embedded database Oracle
>   Berkeley DB Java Edition.

[image: ASHViewer Screenshot]

It may seem that an application called ASH Viewer wouldn't work with Standard Edition because it does not have the Diagnostic pack and therefore does not have v$Active_Session_History, but it does.  When a new connection is created it asks whether the target is Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition.  If Standard Edition is selected it does not use v$Active_Session_History.  This can be demonstrated by querying the view with control_management_pack_access set to NONE, which among other things causes the view to return no records.

Pros:

- Free
- Allows a specific time range selection (OEM can't do this)

Cons:

- Not server based (Statistics collection is repeated for each user)
- No web interface
- Requires the equivalent of System level privileges
- Interface isn't very polished (Font stretching, OS integration, etc.)
- Not RAC aware (must run separately for each instance)

Answer (score 1):

L[image]ighty Orachrome looks awesome

see

http://orachrome.com

I haven't used it but have seen demos and the videos. It's the only tool that looks to have improved on Enterprises Managers top activity interface.

Answer (score -2):

[dbTrends for Oracle STATSPACK](http://www.spviewer.com/dbtrends.html) provides cost-effective database monitoring and tuning solution for companies which do not have very expensive Oracle tuning and diagnostic packs licenses required to access AWR. dbTrends is based on free STATSPACK engine that does not require additional licensing. dbTrends provides much more insights into AWR and STATSPACK performance data comparing with standard Oracle Enterprise Manager or third party vendors and allows to quickly identify performance trends and issues by comparing "good" and "bad" intervals of database operation. dbTrends is an ideal software tool for Oracle consultaning companies which manage remote customers' databases. dbTrends provides unique functionality to compare and analyze standard text performance reports generated by Oracle AWR and STATSPACK tools.

[image: dbTrends for Oracle STATSPACK]
[image: dbTrends for Oracle STATSPACK]