# Monitoring multiple Oracle databases on a single screen

Tags: oracle, monitoring

We would like to monitor database activity of multiple Oracle databases on a single screen (10g and 11gR2), divided by the number of databases.

Some tools are offered here: [Tools to monitor Oracle Database Performance on Standard Edition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/tools-to-monitor-oracle-database-performance-on-standard-edition), but we couldn't figure out if these products support such an activity. Currently, we are trying to merge and align Enterprise Manager's graphs in a html page using frame tags.